# Assinging a pointer-to-pointer dynamic array with values

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I'm currently reading Jumping into C++ by Alex Allain and am stuck on Chapter 14's Practice Problem number 1.

1. Write a function that builds a two-dimensional multiplication table with arbitrary sizes for two dimensions.

I'm having trouble actually assigning the times table to the array but all these nested loops are giving me a headache! I'm getting an output of "999999999".

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int **p_p_tictactoe;
    p_p_tictactoe = new int*[3]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        p_p_tictactoe[i] = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            p_p_tictactoe[i][j] = 1;

            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++)
                {
                    p_p_tictactoe[i][j] = y * t;
                }
            }
            cout << p_p_tictactoe[i][j];
        }   
    }
    cin.get();


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        delete[] p_p_tictactoe[i];
    delete[] p_p_tictactoe;

}
```

Comment: You're overwriting the value at `p_p_tictactoe[i][j]` 16 times with `p_p_tictactoe[i][j] = y * t;`. It's the same as you'd do `p_p_tictactoe[i][j] = 3 * 3;` once...

Comment: @zenith Yes, but the variables i,y,j and t should be different those 16 times?

Comment: Yes they are but only the last `y * t` is left there because you overwrite them to the same `p_p_tictactoe[i][j]` on each iteration.

Comment: How do I not overwrite them?

Comment: Depends. What do you want to do? Do you want to *add* `y * t` to the old value? Or something else?

Comment: Btw use functions to get rid of nested loops.

Comment: Have the 2d array as the data being a multiplication table

Comment: So essentially just `i * j` for each `[i][j]` in the array? I don't think you need another double loop inside the first double loop for that.

Comment: Or `(i + 1) * (j + 1)` if you want to start from 1.

Comment: I get an output of 123246369 with that code, not sure why.

Comment: That's the multiplication table. Just not in a very readable form.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Just realized silly me

Comment: @Coder77 If you were really "jumping into C++", the authors would not have you write code like this:  `int **p_p_tictactoe;  p_p_tictactoe = new int*[3];`  Instead, they would have used `std::vector`

Comment: That's the exact syntax the book used @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @Coder77 That's my point.  In C++, you have `std::vector`, and your book didn't "jump you into C++".

Comment: Perhaps it will use std::vector later in the book.